# Magento 2 Knockout JS How to bind data from response of ajax call

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I want to bind image source to following div.

```
<div class="head_label"><img class="bank_photo" data-bind="attr:{src: bankImage}"></div>
```

Following is my ajax call and their is my variable which I want to bind to image src.

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',     
    'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator',
    'mage/validation'           
],
function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    var bankImage = '';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Nitesh_Payment/payment/form',
            transactionResult: ''
        },
        ajaxCall: function(){
                $('#input-cc-number').blur(function(){
                    var cc = $(this).val();
                    var cc_length = cc.length;
                    if(cc_length>=6){
                        var data= {cc:cc}
                        $.ajax({
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url: url,
                            data: data,
                            type: 'post',
                            success: function(result)
                            {
                                var myObj = result;
                                this.bankImage = myObj.image;
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                alert("You Failed!");
                            }
                        });

                    }

                }); 
        },  

    });
}
);
```

Also I am unable to access bankImage variable inside Ajax call.
Please tell me how to access that variable in ajax function.

Comment: Solved : HTML
**<img id="bankImage" class="bank_photo" src="">**
And in success function added ->
**$('#bankImage').attr('src',result.image);**
my problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

`<img id="bankImage" class="bank_photo" src="">`

And in success function added ->

`$('#bankImage').attr('src',result.image);`

My problem solved

Comment: This is not bind data in knockout, miss-leading title.

Comment: @Tomi why you down vote my answer instead of question edit?

Answer (score 6):

At first, add your variable to defaults object, and you will be able to set default value for field.

```
defaults: {
    bankImage : null
}
```

Define your variable as observable

```
/**
 * Initialize observable properties
 */
initObservable: function () {
    this._super()
        .observe('bankImage');

    return this;
},
```

And you need to define correct success handler with component context:

```
success: (function(result) {
    this.bankImage(result.image);
}).bind(this),
```

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply. 
this.bankImage is not function then how can I use that way in success.

Comment: I have used this.bankImage = result.image; 
Instead of
this.bankImage(result.image);
But then also there is no error in console and image is not bind to that div.

Comment: this.bankImage will be rewrited as function, after defining as observable. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: When i have used as u say then there is error
this.bankImage is not a function

Comment: Did you add initObservable function?

Comment: yes initObservable: function () {

                this._super()
                    .observe('bankImage');
                return this;
            }

Comment: Make sure that ajaxCall call after initObservable. How are you trigger ajaxCall?

Comment: Yes after that.
When my form loaded then when Im inserting data into card no input field then ajax call trigger.

Comment: Try to console.log 'this' in success handler and provide code, which call ajaxCall method

Comment: Calling from here <div class="payment-input">
          <input name="cc_number" value="" placeholder="Credit Card Number" id="input-cc-number" maxlength="16" type="text",
          data-bind="event: {blur: ajaxCall}">
        </div>

Comment: try to add `var self = this;` as first line in ajaxCall and use  `self.bankImage(result.image)` instead of `this.bankImage(...`. Moreover if you use `blur` binding in template, you dont need to use jquery observer in ajaxCall.

Comment: " you dont need to use jquery observer in ajaxCall. " means??

Comment: self.bankImage is not a function

Comment: Add console.log(this) on success handler and check console output

Comment: result is <div class="payment-input"> <input name="cc_number" value="" placeholder="Credit Card Number" id="input-cc-number" maxlength="16" type="text", data-bind="event: {blur: ajaxCall}"> </div>

Comment: <img id="bankImage" class="bank_photo" src=""> And in success function added -> $('#bankImage').attr('src',result.image); my problem solved

Comment: observe(['is_haggle_enabled'])